# Problem installing GIMP on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dependencies, gimp

Get following error while trying to install GIMP 2.8 on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp : Depends: libgimp2.0 (<= 2.6.12-z) but 2.8.6-0precise1~ppa is to be installed
        Depends: gimp-data (<= 2.6.12-z) but 2.8.6-0precise1~ppa is to be installed
```

How do I update those dependencies?

Comment: Actually you just need to do `apt-get remove gimp-data && apt-get install gimp`. You get this because your gimp was upgraded from another source.

Answer (score 0):

To install Gimp 2.8.10 on Ubuntu 12.04, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

[image]

<sup>Source:[Thorsten Stettin](https://plus.google.com/+ThorstenStettin/posts)</sup>